# Is it possible to beat the neutral ending boss?

Tags: undertale-yellow

I reached what is presumably the boss of Undertale Yellow's neutral route:

> After Flowey killed Martlet, I was thrown into a fight against a nightmare version of Flowey. Every time I die my soul refuses to shatter and the fight resumes. Flowey's dialogue implies it's an unwinnable fight. Selecting any option other than Check or Spare rejust gets ignored. I've been at the fight for a while but can't tell if I'm making any progress. Considering this game is a prequel to Undertale, a game where Clover is already dead, I'm starting to suspect this could *actually* be an unwinnable fight.

Is it possible to win this fight?

Comment: Isn't it covered in [the wiki](https://undertaleyellow.fandom.com/wiki/Flowey/In_Battle#Meta_Flowey)? I didn't play so not sure what "concluding the battle" means exactly, and if it's considered "winning".

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda I had been trying to avoid spoilers. I've since cleared the fight and am writing up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an ending to the fight. After enough trial and error I was able to complete it.

> Occasionally Flowey will trap you in a maze set in the overworld. According to the [Undertale Yellow wiki](https://undertaleyellow.wiki.gg/wiki/Flowey/In_Battle#Flowey), in order to progress the fight you need to clear Flowey's maze 3 times. You get a checkpoint after clearing each maze. After the third maze is cleared you are put into a hallway you need to run down.

Further spoilers

> After finishing the hallway, you will be sent into a second phase of the Flowey fight. This phase is also completable. You must destroy 6 of Flowey's petals. You get a checkpoint for every 2 petals destroyed.